# PHP get id from explode/foreach loop and calculate price

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to sum all the product_price in a MySQL table for the multiple `product_id`.

When I run `$result = "SELECT SUM(product_price) AS product_price FROM products";`, it sums up all product_price which works correctly.

When I run `$result = "SELECT SUM(product_price) AS product_price FROM products WHERE product_id = $school_product_id";`, it gives me an array error.

I want the query to get all 4 ids from the `explode`/`foreach` and display the total price.

Database field that is being exploded looks like "1,2,3,4" which match `product_id` in the `products` table below.

```
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $school_subject_products = $row["school_subject_products"];  // (output is 1,2,3,4)
    $school_product_id = explode(',', $school_subject_products); // (explode 1,2,3,4 to use in query below to calculate all 4 product_id's product_price)


    $result = "SELECT SUM(product_price) AS product_price FROM products WHERE product_id = ??????????"; //<------ how do I get it to search for all 4 product_ids and total the price of all the product_ids
    $price_result = $mysqli->query($result);
    $row = $price_result->fetch_assoc();
    $sum = $row['product_price'];
    echo $sum;

    ?>
```

Comment: the big issue here is having "1,2,3,4" in your database, you need to normalise that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: `SELECT SUM(product_price) AS product_price FROM products WHERE product_id IN(...)` - Use in instead, and fix the SQL Injection issues.

Comment: All your `while` loops are just overwriting the variable each time through the loop. They need to combine all the results.

Comment: Why do you have `while` loops for queries that only return one row?

Comment: @Barmar - agreed the while loop being disassociated with the query is not going to work to well.  Each iteration of that loop overwrites the data.  I think there we be only one result there so the while loop could be removed.  But the foreach has the same if not bigger issue.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution is to normalize your data so you don't have a comma-separated list.

If you can't do that, you can use `JOIN` with `FIND_IN_SET()` to match against a comma-separated list, rather than doing multiple queries and using `explode()`.

```
SELECT SUM(product_price) AS product_price
FROM products AS p
JOIN select_subject AS s ON FIND_IN_SET(p.product_id, s.school_subject_products)
WHERE school_id = $selected_school_id AND school_year_id = $selected_year_id AND  school_subject_id = $school_subject_selected
```

Comment: I was just thinking about the same thing, same table no need to query it again in most cases. I don't use `FIND_IN_SET` much so I wouldn't have been able to do it in my head alone.  As always a great answer....